# Как назвать папки в проекте?

Tags: php, laravel, сервер, soap

В общем дилемма: есть задача сделать промежуточный сервер, который будет JSON REST API клиента (json запрос) преобразовывать в soap и отправлять на другой сервер, в ответ получать soap, преобразовывать в json, отметать лишние данные и отдавать клиенту.
В чем вопрос: как назвать папку где все это будет лежать? как архитектурно сделать это красиво? (сервак будет выполнять и другие задачи, например отдачу новостей)
Так же кроме этого будут другие внешние сервисы, типа отправки смс, где такие классы писать? имею ввиду как организовать папки?

Comment: щас все напишут что это тупой вопрос, НО я тебя понимаю, чел, у самого такой вопрос был(только не php))

Comment: Самый лучший совет, прочитайте книгу - Чистый код. Создание, анализ и рефакторинг   https://www.litmir.me/bd/?b=259244  и всё станет на свои места ))  Спасибо потом скажите :)

Comment: @Arsen увы я возможно не успею ее прочитать =) Нужно здесь и сейчас

Comment: Назовите "API" - это всего лишь название папки.

Comment: Погуглите Services, DDD...